# Copy Paste multiple Illustrator layers into Photoshop for individual editing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, layers

I have a world map in Illustrator with a layer for each individual country. I want to copy and paste all layers into photoshop so that I can edit the colour blend for each individual country. I do not want to copy and paste 200 times to get 200 shape layers. Can I copy then another way so i can edit each country individually?

Answer (score 5):

You should make an export of your `.ai` file as a `.psd`.

After `File > Export...`, at the bottom of the dialog you must choose `psd` as your exporting format and when you click `save` you get a new dialog in which you can choose if you are exporting as a flat image or with the different layers. To do this you must check the `Write Layers` option. After that you would be good to open that file in Photoshop and tune your individual countries.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that. Unfortunately, It did not work. I cannot select any individual country, I actually cannot change anything.. Can you help?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue now. Didn't create the layers in Photoshop?

Comment: Hi raulailgo, It did not create layers. Just one layer which I cannot change. Strange! i will keep trying.. Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering if it has anything to do with transparency? The countries are at 100% opacity...

Comment: When exporting to .psd you need to A) not use *any* blending modes or transparency in Illustrator. and B) export tot he *same* color mode as the AI document.

Comment: Hi Scott, Thanks for your advice. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I still only saves as one layer. However, I am a complete novice and I wonder it is because every individual country vector is a 'sublayer'? Perhaps this is where I am going wrong? Any advice appreciated! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem, before you export you need to create each item on it's own layer - that way you tell Illustrator to create multiple layers, then PSD will pick those up.

Hope this helps.

P.S:Everything else to do is correct.

Answer (score 0):

what i do is open your `AI` file in `Adobe Fireworks` then save as a `PSD` file.

Now your file should have all the shapes in Photoshop on their own layer as vector shapes.

simples :)

Comment: Thanks Sat. I downloaded Fireworks but it will not open any .AI files. I get an 'Internal Error' message. Seems this is a common roble. Thanks anyway for you help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem today and the solution stated above did not work for me. With so much trial, experiment and research here's what worked for me..

I created new layers in AI for all my images... then click the image each and drag each one to new layers I've created.

After that, I exported that file ticking Options: Write layers, etc.. and saved it as PSD file.

When I opened it on Photoshop .. all layers are now visible.. ! Hope this will help others you'll encounter such problem.

Comment: Hi JenL, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

this was super simple, highlight the layers you want to export into a new .psd and then drag them on top of a new canvas. EASY.

Comment: Hi Doug, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your input. Could you please explain a bit more? What kind of canvas, in Photoshop or Illustrator? Thanks! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!